# Ethernet switch signal quality

Tags: switch, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, cat5e

Is there a (significant) signal quality difference between ethernet switches?

n other words:

A 1000base-t, do some switches allow longer cable runs than other switches?

Comment: Your question, although valid, misses important aspects for ethernet technologies. Whilst a gigabit (and any other network media) may be capable of longer distances, there is a high risk of signal degradation,ultimately resulting in data corruption between switches. This is why both devices and cables have standards compliance. Cat6 is the certified gigabit cable and has a maximum length of 100m for a 1000BASE-T.

Comment: @BigChris Cat5e is certified for 1GbE operation up to 100m. Cat6A is certified for 10GbE up to 100m. The Cat6 standard has been discouraged for a decade or two, but works for 1GbE@100m and 10GbE@55m.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a (significant) signal quality difference between ethernet
>   switches?

No.

> A 1000base-t, do some switches allow longer cable runs than other
>   switches?

Nope. If you need longer runs, use fiber. Long runs of copper, even if under spec, put your equipment at high risk of inductive lightning damage, which is another reason to use fiber.

Comment: You can also use intermediary switches for longer runs, but there are various disadvantages.

Comment: Yes you can. That said, I've never once regretted forking out for a longer fiber run when necessary. I'm fairly certain I'd be kicking myself if I chose to use daisy-chained switches for these.